# Swing repainting issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm using [Abeille Forms Designer](http://java.net/projects/abeille) as my Swing app's WYSIWYG editor.  I've used this tool to create a `test.jfpr` file which I then import into my Eclipse project and put on the classpath. Then I just create a `JFrame` that uses that file as its `FormPanel`, and when the application launches - voila - you have a very nice looking GUI that took zero programming effort. I love it!

The only problem is that when the app loads up, nothing inside the "client area" (Windows terminology) is drawing - the menubar, as well as the main content of the screen.

When I resize the `JFrame`'s window, everything immediately draws/paints and looks great.

If I then do something (selecting a menu item, etc.) that should change the main screen, nothing happens. But if I resize the window, then *bam*! I see the changes take effect.

To me, it seems that this is a painting/re-painting issue, where there is a disconnect between my application logic and Abeille forms I created.

**Is there a way - in Swing - to programmatically force the entire window (client- and non-client areas alike) to repaint/refresh?** If not, then does anybody have an idea as to what is happening here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register an [actionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) on the menu. Once your menu routine is done, call the [repaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) function on the appropriate component.

Some additional work might required to avoid flickering.

Comment: 1) There was mention of a menu bar, but no menu.  2) Presuming there is a menu, it looks very unprofessional to tell the user 'if you don't see anything, activate a menu item'. 3) Calling `repaint()` is usually the wrong solution.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: The answer is made for the person who posted the answer. I will not provide a NASA rocket to solve what seems to be a homework. Furthermore, SO is not made to measure the degree of professionalism but to help people (professional and enthusiast programmers)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to mKorbel's suggestions,

- Verify that you are constructing the GUI on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Ensure that you invoke `setVisible()` only *after* calling `pack()` on the enclosing `Window`.

Answer (score 1):

1) `you have a very nice looking GUI that took zero programming effort. I love it!`

- use [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

2) `If I then do something (selecting a menu item, etc.) that should change 
    the main screen, nothing happens. But if I resize the window, then bam! 
    I see the changes take effect.`

- use [Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) layed with proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

3) `Is there a way - in Swing - to programmatically force the entire window 
    (client- and non-client areas alike) to repaint/refresh?`

- write Swing GUI standard way, by your hands, [support here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing)

4) `If not, then does anybody have an idea as to what is happening here?`

- this Framework is based on based on [JGoodies FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/forms/), then you have to knows how this custom `LayoutManager` works

Comment: Me: "Whenever I drink Pepsi, I burp. How do I stop myself from burping?" You: "Drink Coca Cola." No. Perhaps the problem is **soda**.

Comment: hmmm then this question is posted on wrong forum, there is about coding only, please to try some of `KinderDJ Forum`, there you'll see miracles about drinks

Comment: I was making comment not of the concern with soda, more or less with herpylderp API for Swing and SWT. In this way you contradict yourself.